# Incluir arquivo jar em projeto Maven

Tags: java, maven

Como faço para incluir um .jar avulso em um projeto Maven?

**Obs:**

O jar que preciso incluir possui dependência de outros 3 arquivos jar.

Os jars em questão são do projeto [Morena](http://www.gnome.sk/Morena/morena.html)

**Tentativa #1**

Criei um diretório lib e coloquei lá o jar.

Adicionei a dependência no POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/morena7.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

**Ao construir:**

> Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for
>   meuPacote:MeuProjeto:jar:1.0 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for
>   abc:abc:jar should not point at files within the project directory,
>   ${basedir}/lib/morena7.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects
>   @ line 30, column 25

Na execução ocorre java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Existem várias formas de se resolver isso.

## Mantendo seu repositório

O ideal é instalar os jars em um repositório de sua empresa/casa. Para isso você precisa de um servidor com [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) ou [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/).

A vantagem em ter seu próprio repositório é que você pode usar para gerenciar as versões dos seus projetos também.

Outra vantagem é que ele faz cache do repositório central e seu ambiente fica mais rápido.

## Dependências com escopo `system`

Você também pode apontar o caminho de dependências do tipo `system`. Considere o seguinte exemplo:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Essas dependências também podem estar dentro do projeto. Use a variável `${basedir}` para indicar o diretório base do projeto.

O problema desta abordagem é que você precisa manter os Jars no repositório, o que não é muito indicado.

Veja a [documentação](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) para mais detalhes.

**Nota: o Maven adicionou uma restrição ao uso de libs dentro do projeto, como pode ser observado no erro editado na pergunta. Deve-se usar então um diretório fora do projeto.**

## Instalando dependências no repositório local

Outra solução é usar o plugin `install` para instalar os jars num repositório local. Isso pode ser feito com o comando `mvn install:install-file` e os parâmetros adequados. Veja a [documentação](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) mais mais detalhes.

Exemplo:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=morena7.jar -DgroupId=sk.gnome \
    -DartifactId=morena -Dversion=7.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Note que os dados acima foram inventados e só funcionarão no ambiente em que foram instalados.

O problema desta a abordagem é que o processo de instalação precisa ser repetido em cada ambiente, isto é, em cada máquina de desenvolvimento e no servidor de Integração Contínua, se houver.

Comment: editei minha pergunta com a tentativa que fiz seguindo sua dica.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Você deve estar usando uma das versões mais novas do Maven. Acabei de notar que eles adicionaram essa restrição. Entretanto você pode colocar os arquivos numa pasta fora do projeto e especificar o caminho absoluto. Outra alternativa é instalar o jar no seu repositório local usando um groupId e artifactId quaisquer. Vou atualizar a resposta com isso.

Comment: Cheguei a conclusão que o melhor a fazer é instalar o Nexus ou Artifactory mesmo, pois facilitará o trabalho na manutenção.

Comment: @NilsonUehara Se você tem essa opção, é realmente o melhor caminho!